# Order of declaration does not matter for a struct?

Tags: c, struct, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void f(struct emp);
struct emp{
char name[20];
int age;
};
int main(){
    struct emp  e = {"nikunj", 23}  ;
    f(e);
    return 0;
}

void f(struct emp e){
    printf("%s %d\n", e.name, e.age);
}
```

Running the above code gives the following errors

```
nikunjbanka@ubuntu:~$ gcc hello2.c -o main.out
hello2.c:3:15: warning: ‘struct emp’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
hello2.c:3:15: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
hello2.c: In function ‘main’:
hello2.c:10:2: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
hello2.c: At top level:
hello2.c:14:6: error: conflicting types for ‘f’
hello2.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘f’ was here
```

But the book test your C skills says that the order of prototype declaration and structure declaration in the program does not matter. I want to ask whether the order matters or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the order absolutely does matter.

Re-order your code such that the definition of `struct emp` appears before the function prototype for `f`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct emp{
  char name[20];
  int age;
};

void f(struct emp);

...
```

gcc is actually trying to tell you that you did things in the wrong order, however the compiler messages are a little bit confusing if this is your first time reading through them.

These two warnings:

```
hello2.c:3:15: warning: ‘struct emp’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
hello2.c:3:15: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
```

indicate that the type of 'struct emp' was not known at the time gcc compiled line 3 of your file.  The compiler will typically try to infer a default type & size for the unknown `struct emp` and almost always guesses incorrectly because it has no idea how you will eventually declare `struct emp`.

This error:

```
hello2.c:10:2: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
```

indicates that you are trying to call function 'f' with an actual parameter type that is different than the formal parameter type that gcc (incorrectly) inferred when it compiled line 3 of the file.

This error and associated note:

```
hello2.c:14:6: error: conflicting types for ‘f’
hello2.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘f’ was here
```

indicates that the formal parameter type on line 14 (which is now known to be the type `struct emp` you declared on lines 4 through 7) did not match the formal parameter type that gcc (again incorrectly) inferred on line 3.

Bottom line: define all of your types before the prototypes that refer to them, and you should be fine.

You may also find your code is more readable if you use

```
typedef struct {
   char name[20];
   int  age;
} emp_t;
```

And then you can use `emp_t` rather than `struct emp` throughout the subsequent code.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option - this change will fix it too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 struct emp;   /* <--- add this line */

void f(struct emp); /* <-- now this refers to that */
struct emp{        /* <-- and this defines the same thing */
char name[20];     /* and you didn't need to move things around. */
int age;
};
```

In a complex project it's not always easy to resolve all the ordering issues, this can be helpful.

Note that when f is actually  f(struct emp*) --not f(struct emp)- then you may be able to define f() without including a definition of the struct layout.
This is because the compiler can work with pointers to structs that are named, but not defined - provided you only do certain things to them (store them, return them, pass them to other functions; compare them to NULL, or to other pointers to the same thing... cast them to other pointer types...) - but you can't do pointer arithmetic, or access members (obviously) or ask for sizeof(*p) if p is a pointer to an unspecified struct. The compiler will let you know :-)